# Design a data structure that moves referenced element to the beginning. C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I need to design a data structure that allows access to an array by index in a similar way as a common array. But after referencing *the i-th element*, I should move it to the beginning.
It can be easily done with a *linked list* and *O(n) access complexity*, but I need a way to achieve better performance. If you wish, you may assume that inserting in such a data structure is prohibited.

For example:

```
T=[5, 4, 9, 45] - Initial state
 1. Access to 2-th element => T[2] returns 9, now T=[9,5,4,45](We move 2-th element to the beginning)
 2. Access to 3-th element => T[3] returns 45, now T=[45,9,5,4](We move 3-th element to the beginning)
 3. T[0] returns 45, T=[45,9,5,4]
 4. T[2] returns 5, T=[5,45,9,4]
```

I hope the problem is clear. Please suggest any related links or pieces of code.

Edited:
I have heard about Cartesian Tree and Ropes. Which one is better to apply here and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Balanced [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) guarantee amortized O(log N) indexing, deletion and insertion time. The operation in question can be decomposed into a sequence of the three.

Comment: How about Cartesian Tree? Can it be somehow used for my question?

Comment: Sure, it can be easily implemented using cartesian tree by implicit key, with O(logN) for all operations.

Comment: Then, is it better to use Cartesian Tree or Rope data structure here?

Comment: @ardenit: can you explain how to use a cartesian tree in here, and how do you guarantee O(logN) time (seems they can easily degenerate to linear lists)?

Comment: It's cartesian tree *by implicit key*. It's like an array with indices, and it can remove/add elements from/to any index in O(logN). Of course it can degenerate to linear list, but there is a proof that with probability tending to one cartesian tree's height is less than 4logN - that's how cartesian tree works.

Comment: @ardenit: I know what a cartesian tree is. I don't understand though what's the implicit key you're using and how do you orchestrate the insertion/lookup/deletion to satisfy the requirements. Can you provide a link explaining that or write a detailed answer? Also, average time complexity is not the same as amortized, which in turn is not the same as worst-case...

Comment: I'm talking about this: https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/102364/index.html

Comment: @ardenit: Oh I see. What they describe is essentially the same as ropes, except that they store values in the inner nodes too, and they don't guarantee that the tree is balanced.